# extfld for an array of numbers

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

I have an array declared as a subfield of a DS as below:

```
MatchingWorkKeysList                     extfld('MATCHWKEYS') dim(50);
```

The MATCHWKEYS is defined in the external file structure as :

```
MATCHWKEYS       CHAR      (550)
```

So I get 50 elements of length 11.

The question is, is there a way to create an array of 50 numbers, each 11(NUMERIC (11)) digits in length?

I would need to refer to the external file using EXTNAME and EXTFLD

Answer (score 1):

Define the numeric array as an overlay of the external field.

Here's a example with a 22-byte field and 2 elements in the array. I didn't need to use EXTFLD.

```
dcl-f myfile;                                 
dcl-ds ds extname('MYFILE' : *input);         
   num_array zoned(11) dim(2) overlay(nums);  
end-ds;                                       
read MYFILE ds;                               
dsply num_array(1);                           
dsply num_array(2);                           
*inlr = '1';
```

Here's how I defined the file:

```
 A          R REC               
 A            NUMS          22A
```

I put the value '1111111111122222222222' in NUMS.

Here's what it displays:

```
DSPLY  11111111111
DSPLY  22222222222
```

Update:

Following @barbara's advice in the comment below, I have tried implementing the DS as below:

```
dcl-ds P_IAC3002L                          extname('IAC3002_L') qualified template;
    LISTROWNumber                            extfld('LISTROWNBR');
    WorkTitle                                extfld('WORKTITLE');
    OriginalWorkTitle                        extfld('WRKTITLEOR');
    TypeOfWorkTitle                          extfld('WRKTITLETY');
    TitleTypeDescription                     extfld('TITLEDESC');
    OriginalVersionInd                       extfld('WRKORGIND');
    OriginalVersionIndDescription            extfld('WRKORGDESC');
    Role                                     extfld('ROLE' );
    RoleDescription                          extfld('ROLEDESC');
    StatusOfWork                             extfld('WRKSTS' );
    WorkStatusDescription                    extfld('WRKSTSDESC');
    WorkKey                                  extfld('WORKKEY');
    WorkTitleNumber                          extfld('WRKTITLENO');
    WorkMatchIndicator                       extfld('WRKMATCHIN');
    WorkCCIndicator                          extfld('WRKCCIND');
    OtherTitlesExist                         extfld('OTHTITLIND');
    WorkIsReferenced                         extfld('WRKISREF');
    WorkIsActive                             extfld('WRKISACT');
    AgreementExceptionExists                 extfld('PAGEXCEP');
    WorkReferencesList                       extfld('WORKREFS') dim(10); 
    WorkReferencesCountExceedsLimit          extfld('RFCNMRTHLT');  
    MatchingWorkKeysCountExceedsLimit        extfld('MTWCMRTHLT');
    MatchingWorkKeysList                     zoned(11) dim(11) overlay(MATCHWKEYS);
  end-ds;
```

This compiles fine. But I need to position the "MatchingWorkKeysList" field first followed by "MatchingWorkKeysCountExceedsLimit" . This doesn't compile  and the error is :

```
*RNF3701 20      1 Keyword is not allowed for a subfield definition; keyword is 
                   ignored.
```

It seems the subfield using the overlay has to be defined a the last field.

Is there any way to order the fields as I require ?

Comment: the `dcl-ds ds` threw me for a second... I'd suggest `dcl-ds myDs` . ;)

Comment: Thanks @barbara. The problem with this approach is, I should have mentioned it earlier. This is just one of the subfields of the DS. I have a whole bunch of other subfields defined with EXTFLD and the DS is using EXTNAME. So this wont compile.

Comment: @Theju112, I don't understand why my approach won't work. My DS is using EXTNAME too. And I could have had other fields defined with EXTFLD. I could have even given the NUMS  field a different name, such as Numbers, using EXTFLD(NUMS). In that case, I would have coded OVERLAY(Numbers).

Comment: Hi @BarbaraMorris I have added an edit to my question on why the compilation fails but its still pending review. Basically, if I try to use overlay for the last subfield of the DS, compilation fails.

Comment: Hi @Theju112. Thanks for clarifying your code. I tried your code and did not get an error, but then I tried moving MatchingWorkKeyList above MatchingWorkKeysCountExceedsLimit, and I did get the error. Indeed, you have to do all your EXTFLD definitions before you do any extra "ordinary" subfields. If you mean that you want the actual storage for the MatchingWorkKeysList subfield to precede the storage for the MatchingWorkKeysCountExceedsLimit subfield, that's impossible. The order of the external subfields cannot be changed. Why do you need the subfields to be in a different order?

Comment: Hello @BarbaraMorris, this program is to be used as an API and this is the order in which the API call expects results. So was wondering if possible at all.

Comment: @Theju112, I would define the API to have separate parameters for each item. Your program would then set assign the API parameters from the subfields of the data structure.

Comment: @Theju112, there's another way to handle it, if you really want the API parameter to be a data structure ... You could also define a separate data structure for the API, with the subfields in any order you need. The subfields of your API data structure could be defined LIKE the subfields of your externally-described data structure.